# angularjs tabs directive, displaying only first item instead of 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using following directive in order to utilize tabs section inside view

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', []);
    var directives = angular.module('app');
    directives.directive('showtab',
        function () {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(element).tab('show');
                    });
                }
            };
        });
})();
```

**myview.html**

```
 <div class="tab-content" ng-controller="homeController as vm">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-One"
           ng-repeat="item in vm.data" ng-if="item.Type === 'One'">
           {{item.Title}}
       ...
      </div>         
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-Two"
            ng-repeat="item in vm.data" ng-if="item.Type === 'Two'">
          {{item.Title}}
           ...
      </div>
</div>
```

On page load data is displayed fine, on first active tab it's displayed 10 items as it should.

When I click to tab Two it displays only one item instead of 20 and when I click back to tab one it displays one item instead of 10.

Comment: get rid of using bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap instead...it has no dependencies like jQuery and has lots of additional anular integration features

Comment: thx, I will try.